# Make a function return a value only when an Angular HTTP request has finished

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-observable

Hello i am creating an angular async validator that has to wait for the response from a HttpRequest from a service.

I a need a function to return an observable of the information returned by the http call.

If a try diferent codes:

1- It doesn´t work because a is not defined due to the httprequest hasn´t finished when the function returns the a.

```
searchValue(controlName, controlValue){
   this.cts.getByParam(controlName, controlValue) // Call a function on the service that make a 
   HTTPrequest and make a subject emit a value.
   let a
   this.cts.dataGetByParamSubject.subscribe(res=>{
   a=(res)
})
return of(a)
}
```

2- It doesn't work because it doesn´t return any value.

```
searchValue(controlName, controlValue){
       this.cts.getByParam(controlName, controlValue) // Call a function on the service that make a 
       HTTPrequest and make a subject emit a value.
       let a
       this.cts.dataGetByParamSubject.subscribe(res=>{
       a=(res)
       return of(a)
    })
    }
```

3- It returns a Subscription not an Observable.

```
searchValue(controlName, controlValue){
           this.cts.getByParam(controlName, controlValue) // Call a function on the service that make a 
           HTTPrequest and make a subject emit a value.
           let a
           return this.cts.dataGetByParamSubject.subscribe(res=>{
           a=(res)
           return of(a)
        })
        }
```

4- It returns an observable that when you map it the res is a Subscriber and i got lost.

```
searchValue(controlName, controlValue){
           this.cts.getByParam(controlName, controlValue) // Call a function on the service that make a 
           HTTPrequest and make a subject emit a value.
           let a
           return of(this.cts.dataGetByParamSubject.subscribe(res=>{
           a=(res)
           return of(a)
        })
        })
```

Service side:

```
getByParam(property, value): Observable<HttpResponses> { 
    let data
    let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('schema', this.tipoConfiguracion.codigo)
    .set('property', property)
    .set('value', value)
      this.http.get<HttpResponses>(this.apiUrl + 'validation', {params: params}).subscribe(res=>{
        this.dataGetByParamSubject.next({message: res.message, data: res.data, error: res.error})
     })
     return
  }
```

How could i do this to work?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**[UPDATE]:** I've made some editions per comments.

```js
searchValue(controlName, controlValue) {
  // you don't need dataGetByParamSubject as it emits an object with the same
  // shape of the returning of this.cts.getByParam
  return this.cts.getByParam(controlName, controlValue);
}
```

Notice that as you have just one observable that have to be subscribed to after you get the return of `getByParam`, you also could've used `mergeMap` or  `concatMap` with no distinction.

Also, notice the `take(1)` operator at the end of the pipe chain. I've added it because it looks like that `this.cts.dataGetByParamSubject` is a long-lived stream and you just want one value, is that right?

You can learn a lot about operators on [https://www.learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

On the service, you should do:

```js
getByParam(property, value): Observable<HttpResponses> { 
  let data
  let params = new HttpParams()
      .set('schema', this.tipoConfiguracion.codigo)
      .set('property', property)
      .set('value', value);

  // there's no point in the dataGetByParamSubject here, as you will use 
  // it directly in your component.
  return this.http.get<HttpResponses>(this.apiUrl + 'validation', {params: params}).pipe(
    map((res: any) => ({
      message: res.message, 
      data: res.data, 
      error: res.error
    })
  ));
}
```

Comment: When a i try this it gives me an error. 'Cannot read property pipe of undefined'.

Comment: Make sure `this.cts.getByParam(controlName, controlValue)` is **returning** an observable. If you post that method in your question, I can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the service side. I think i am not doing the return well.

Comment: I've edited my answer, but notice that if you're not using `this.dataGetByParamSubject` anywhere else, so I got rid of it.